# How to use $_GET in mysqli/php to extract an integer from the URL?

Tags: php, mysqli

How to use $_GET in MySQLI/PHP to extract an integer from the URL to be bind into a SQL statement?

Making a blog esque page where the content is stored in a database, meaning that there can be multiple pages without the need for numerous files.

On the index page, there are links to these pages, once clicked, the URL is changed to the blog page with the ID posted:

pages/article.php?id=1

Here's how -

```
for($x=0;$x<$articlesFetched;++$x){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    //create div
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="articleDiv">';
    echo "<img class='img-responsive' id='articleImage' src=".$row['articleThumbnail'].">";  
    echo '<h5><a href="article.php?id='.$row['articleId'].'">'.$row['articleHeadline'].'</a></h5>';
    echo '<p>',$row['articleSummary']," ",'</p>';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<p>' , $row['articleTopic']," | ",'</p>';
    echo '<p>', $row['articleSubTopic']," | ",'</p>';
    echo '<p>',$row['articleDate']," | ",'</p>';
    echo '</div>';            
    echo '</div>';
}
```

PS - excuse the indentation, copy and paste seems to mess the formatting up.

To tell the difference between page content, I have used an ID, which can be binded to the SQL statement e.g. `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?'`

Heres how:

```
$id=$_GET['articleId'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Article WHERE articleId=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
```

However, when the web page is opened there is no content, as there is a Undefined index error, pointing `$id=$_GET['articleId'];`

When checking if  `$id=$_GET['articleId'];` variable is set, the output is FALSE.

Comment: use $id=$_GET['id']; instead of $id=$_GET['articleId']; or
use pages/article.php?articleId=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your URL become something like this:-

```
article.php?id=1 //for example
```

So yo need to do:-

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // not $_GET['articleId']
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `$_GET` you have used `articleId` but what You have pasted on url is `id`. Both names must be the same then only it will fetch data.

As an example

```
www.yoursite.com/category?q=myname

<?php
   echo $_GET['q'];  //Output: myname
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url `pages/article.php?id=1`
But You use  `$id=$_GET['articleId'];`

You Simple Use it  `$id=$_GET['id'];`

Code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Article WHERE articleId=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
$stmt->execute();
```